# Android,SAX parser Problem while reading Special charecters

Tags: android, android-emulator, saxparser

i want to parse xml file having HTML tags and special characters,this is my xml file
**while working with SAX parser HTML content in not going to parse and text skipped from Special characters on words**
can any one suggest me how to do it or Any links for the sample code or explain how to do it

Comment: Can u give the url of xml file?